# Spring Boot Security - Get 403 instead of 401 without using bearer token

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bearer-token

I have a problem to handle with the exception handling to get 401 Unauthorized result when I don't use bearer token through Postman.

When I use a user bearer token and send a request to this method, I get this response message shown below

```
{
    "time": "2023-05-29T18:06:23.381897147",
    "httpStatus": "UNAUTHORIZED",
    "header": "AUTH ERROR",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

I want to get this message shown below as it is a user not admin

```
{
    "time": "2023-05-29T18:06:23.381897147",
    "httpStatus": "FORBIDDEN",
    "header": "AUTH ERROR",
    "isSuccess": false
}
```

Moreover, I don't use any bearer token,
It always returns 403 Forbidden instead of 401 Unauthorized.
I selected `No Auth` from `type` part in `Authorization` in `Postman` and then send a request to the endpoint, `handleAccessDeniedError` cannot be called. I think a different exception is used for that.
Which exception should be used?

Here is the relevant part of GlobalExceptionHandler.

```
@ExceptionHandler({AccessDeniedException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccessDeniedError(final AccessDeniedException exception) {
        log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);

        Error error = Error.builder()
                .httpStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                .header(Error.Header.AUTH_ERROR.getName())
                .build();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
```

Here is the sample code snippets

```
@GetMapping
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN')")
public Response<?> getUsers(@RequestBody @Valid UserListRequest listRequest) {

}
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: With the limited code I have above, one of the best practices is to use a nested catch block and define the proper Exception classes. You are returning the default `HttpStatus` as `Forbidden`. Instead of that have multiple catch blocks and capture the actual response status code and send in the response.

Comment: @manojgarimella How can I use mulitple catch blocks in handleAccessDeniedError for this process?

Comment: Don't send `ResponseEntity<>` directly in the `ExceptionHandler`. I would suggest you to handle the logic of setting that status in your controller so you can verify the exception class first.

Comment: @manojgarimella I tried to fix the issue and shared the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution shown below

1 ) Define `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    /**
     * Handles the unauthorized request by sending an "Unauthorized"
     * response with the HTTP status code 401 (SC_UNAUTHORIZED).
     *
     * @param request       the {@link HttpServletRequest} object representing the incoming request
     * @param response      the {@link HttpServletResponse} object used to send the response
     * @param authException the {@link AuthenticationException} that occurred during authentication
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs while sending the response
     */
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

2 ) Inject `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint` class to `SecurityConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalAuthentication
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecurityConfiguration {

....

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity,
AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter, CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint){

httpSecurity.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint);

} 

.....

}
```